# CoreData serialized NSDate convert back into real date

Tags: objective-c, ios, date, nsdate

I using CoreData to store my objects that I fetch from a server.

I have a failure somewhere and cannot figure out what is going wrong. But it looks like it is related to the date stored in the CoreData database. So I opened the sqllite database and tried to compare the dates but since they are, for me, not human readable, is there any way to convert a serialized NSDate back into a human-readable date? (year-month-day for example)

I have the following dates in the CoreData database.
How can I convert them back into a human-readable date format? An online converted would be great since it is very difficult to write just an app for that.

[image: coredata database values]

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are simply timestamps since interval reference date. Here's code you can use to decode them:

```
NSNumber *time = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(d - 3600)];
NSTimeInterval interval = [time doubleValue];    
NSDate *online = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:interval];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS"];

NSLog(@"result: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:online]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use NSLog to view your dates when your code is actually running? Run your fetch query and then output the dates in the debugger:

```
NSDate *myDate; // This is whatever you fetched from your database.

// Show myDate in the debug console.
NSString *output = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:myDate
                                                  dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle 
                                                  timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSLog(@"%@", output);
```